# how to read the data from table 2 based on results from table 1

Tags: c#, sql

I have 2 tables, I read the data from table 1 with

```
SELECT ID 
FROM Users 
WHERE roll = 5
```

Now I need to count in how many rows for each ID appear in Table 2.

Does anybody have an idea how to do that?

Comment: And what does table 2 look like?  What have you tried?  What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think this query solves your problem:

```sql
SELECT 
    COUNT(rep_id) as distinct_user_count
FROM(
  SELECT 
        u.id as rep_Id
    FROM 
        users u
    JOIN
        second_table s
    ON
        s.user_id = u.id
    ORDER by 
        u.id
) as user_count
GROUP by
    rep_id;
```

Since I don't know the structures of your tables, I just made this simply return the number of times each user appears on the second table.

Answer (score 0):

Because I need to SUGGEST what you need, I improvised and wrote SQL query like this:

```
SELECT t2.ID, COUNT(*) 'rowCount'
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
where t1.roll = 5
GROUP BY t2.ID
```

Check here on [DB<>FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7aba0fefb8415b59fe8a58a35ae4fec8)

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT ID,COUNT(*)AS CNTT
FROM TABLE2
GROUP BY ID
```